# How to control the aligning in highchartjs Venn diagram, with React

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm using `highcharts`, the Venn module (`highcharts/modules/venn.js`), and using the `highcharts-react-official` package to support it in React, the need to show the Venn diagram circles as shown here:

[image]

This is what I have now:

[image]

However, I tried to figure out away to do this using `legand.layout` but did not manage to modify the alignment to get the that results, here's what I get.

Any Idea how to do so, if providing the code for that would help more, I'll be happy to share, but I thing either there's an API that I'm no able to find, or its not supported and I have either to find another solution or find a workaround

Really appreciate your time & help

```html
<iframe src="https://codesandbox.io/embed/youthful-cray-7zg7p5?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark"
     style="width:100%; height:500px; border:0; border-radius: 4px; overflow:hidden;"
     title="youthful-cray-7zg7p5"
     allow="accelerometer; ambient-light-sensor; camera; encrypted-media; geolocation; gyroscope; hid; microphone; midi; payment; usb; vr; xr-spatial-tracking"
     sandbox="allow-forms allow-modals allow-popups allow-presentation allow-same-origin allow-scripts"
   ></iframe>
```

Comment: Could you give more details? In general, in a Venn type chart, points are aligned according to their value, [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gt53x06r/).

Comment: Yes, sure
I'll add a jsFieddel for this
thanks @SebastianHajdus

Comment: I have added a code sample of what I'm doing and the current results